# How to sort a complex array like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am a beginner.
How to sort this array according to the orderId value?

```
const fruitFrom = {
  apple: [
      { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 2 }, 
      { 'country': 'France', 'orderId': 2 }
    ],
  pineapple: [
      { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 1 },
      { 'country': 'Italy', 'orderId': 1 }
    ]
};
```

I hope to sort above like the following.
Under each fruite, the orderID will be same.

```
fruitFrom = {
  pineapple: [
          { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 1 },
          { 'country': 'Italy', 'orderId': 1 }
        ],
  apple: [
          { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 2 }, 
          { 'country': 'France', 'orderId': 2 }
        ]
};
```

I try this, but 'can't read undefined properties (reading 'orderId')

```
let sortedArray = fruitFrom.sort((a, b) => a[0].orderId - b[0].orderId)
```

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: What you have is not a valid array.

Comment: I adjusted the array now.

Comment: @yobee310 Yeah, that's still not a valid array or object

Comment: Still not valid. Just copy/paste what you have in your editor (you cannot possible have that, that would throw an error immediately).

Comment: I think your array should be like this :
fruitFrom = [
  {
    apple: [
      {
        country: "U.S",
        orderId: 2,
      },
      {
        country: "France",
        orderId: 2,
      },
    ],
    pinneapple: [
      {
        country: "U.S",
        orderId: 1,
      },
      {
        country: "Italy",
        orderId: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];

Comment: But What happens when one of the apple entry has also a orderId of 1 like pinneapple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your original *array* should actually be an *object*, you could do the following:

```js
const fruitFrom = {
  apple: [
      { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 2 }, 
      { 'country': 'France', 'orderId': 2 }
    ],
  pineapple: [
      { 'country': 'U.S', 'orderId': 1 },
      { 'country': 'Italy', 'orderId': 1 }
    ]
};
const res=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(fruitFrom).sort(([_,[a]],[__,[b]])=>a.orderId-b.orderId));
console.log(res);
```

However, there have been many discussions over the order of properties in JavaScript objects, see here: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: If I change the format of data, it works! I must study about the format of array first. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean your array is like this,

```
const fruitFrom = [
{
  apple: [
    { country: 'U.S', orderId: 2 },
    { country: 'France', orderId: 2 },
  ],
},
{
  pineapple: [
    { country: 'U.S', orderId: 1 },
    { country: 'Italy', orderId: 1 },
  ],
}];
```

If yes, then you should do something like this,

```
const data = fruitFrom.sort((a, b) => (Object.values(a)[0][0].orderId) - (Object.values(b)[0][0].orderId));

console.log(data);
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: If I change the format of data, it works! Thanks a lot.